# unshare -m seemingly not creating mount namespace

Tags: linux, mount, namespace

I ran

```
unshare -mfp sh -c 'mount -tproc none /proc ; ls /proc'
```

That printed a /proc with only directories for PID 1 and PID 3, and exited, leaving me back in my old prompt in the root namespace, as expected.

Then I did

```
ls /proc
```

and I got back a listing without any PID directories. I was expecting my usual /proc full of processes. I had to mount proc again to fix things.

Why is this happening? How do I fix things so the /proc I mounted inside the PID namespace stays local to it?

I tried passing --mount-private to mount, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I'm on Amazon Linux on util-linux 2.23.2.

Comment: `-m` takes an optional argument, are you sure it's not getting treating `fp` as a filename?

Comment: I tried the above on WRL7 (had to add -- BTW to workaround an arg processing bug in unshare). It worked as expected, so sounds like a bug. unshare -mfp -- sh -c 'mount -tproc none /proc ; ls /proc'